# Are the 25 secs running time for a Windows Phone PeriodicTask real time or cpu time?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

A PeriodicTask on WP will run every 30 minutes and is allowed to run for 25 seconds.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=vs.92).aspx

I wonder if those 25 seconds are cpu time or real (calendar) time?
I can imagine that if the user eg is playing a resource intensive game or talking or the phone - your background task (PeriodicTask) will not get that many cpu cycles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Periodic tasks run every 28 +/- 10 minutes.
They run for approximately 25 seconds. It's not exact.
How the length of time that the agent runs for is calculated is not publically documented.

You should plan to write tasks that finish well within this time limit and are robust enough to cope with being terminated if they do run over.

Even if your task was impacted by other operations being performed simultaneously on the device, what would you do about it?

Comment: Well I'm wondering if my background task is heavily impacted by other operations and I only get a slice of the cpu time I was counting on. That could have me constantly breaking the 25-sec contract and be blocked by the system for not finishing on time.

Comment: I think you're spot on though in your reply - one should always make sure that you finish on time. I'm giving a course right now on WP-dev and the question came up.

Comment: @andyhammar I always wrap mine with a call to a timeout after 22 seconds anyway so I'm always sure to not hit the issue.